# If you're mostly on W-2, how much can you benefit from pass-through?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, form-w-2

I'm having trouble understanding how the pass-through deduction works when you make only part of your income as an independent contractor.

Married filing jointly this year, we expect to earn (gross) about $105,000 on W-2 and $27,000 on 1099.

How much would we benefit (if at all) from the pass-through deduction?

Comment: Up to 20% of the 1099 income would not be taxable. Might come back for a thorough answer later: https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/the-new-pass-through-tax-deduction.html

Comment: In other words, our Adjusted Gross Income would be *lower* by (27000 * 20% =) $5408. Correct?